# Trying to understand why expected tokens in a 'mismatched input' ANTLR error does not include some tokens

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Just started playing around with ANTLR and trying to understand an error message I'm getting when attempting to parse erroneous input.
This is my (simple) grammar:

```
grammar Playground;

stmtList: (expr EOS)+;
expr:
IDENTIFIER ('!' | '^') IDENTIFIER
| expr ('*' | '/') expr
| expr ('+' | '-') expr
| INT
| IDENTIFIER;

MAKE: 'make';
INT: '0' | [1-9] [0-9]*;
IDENTIFIER: [a-zA-Z0-9]+;
EQUAL: '='; // Dummy token that can be recognised
EOS: '\r'? '\n';
WS: [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip;
```

This is the text I'm attempting to parse:

```
blah=blah
```

Again, I know this text does not match the grammar defined. The error I'm getting is as follows:

> line 1:4 mismatched input '=' expecting {'*', '/', '+', '-', EOS}

My question is -  how come the expected set of tokens ANTLR recommends does not include tokens like '**!**' and '**^**' which are also defined in the first alternative of the **expr** rule? I feel like I'm missing some fundamental knowledge here. Any help is appreciated!

My expectation was to see an error message that looked like this:

> line 1:4 mismatched input '=' expecting {'!', '^', '*', '/', '+', '-', EOS}

with the '**!**' and '**^**' tokens included in the expected set of tokens.

I'm reading The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference at the moment, and I've also tried generating the tokens using ANTLR's **TestRig**.

Running `grun Playground stmtList -tokens` on `blah=blah` gives me the following output:

```
[@0,0:3='blah',<IDENTIFIER>,1:0]
[@1,4:4='=',<'='>,1:4]
[@2,5:8='blah',<IDENTIFIER>,1:5]
[@3,9:9='\n',<EOS>,1:9]
[@4,10:9='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
```

ANTLR Version: 4.11.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have two alternatives that start with `IDENTIFIER` in your `expr` rule. So they can both be matched with your first identifier. And this is what actually happens. The first `blah` is matched as `IDENTIFIER` and the parser tries the first alt in `expr`. This fails because the next token is `EQUAL`, so it tries the next alt which starts with the left recursive `expr` rule and does the same attempt again. `expr` matches `IDENTIFIER` because of your last alt, so the next step is to match the operators, which all fail. In the end you get the expected tokens for the 2 left recursive alts, because their first  part matches:

[image]

If you remove the last alt in your `expr` rule the outcome is as you expect:

[image]

because now there is no match of `expr` with a single `IDENTIFIER`, so the first alt is what is taken to report the error.

Comment: Out of curiosity - when the parser tries the left recursive `expr` rule, what prevents it from trying to match the first alt rule that failed, again? I'm assuming the parser is keeping some state that lets it know not to try the first alt anymore, or is the `expr` rule rewritten by ANTLR in some way that prevents the first alt from being matched again?

Comment: After typing that, I'm thinking that's just solved by ANTLR's support for direct left-recursive rules

Comment: That's what I wrote in my answer: once the first alt failed and second alt is tried, it will again try the first alt (and fail again). Then the other alts are tried too and finally the last one matches completely (the first identifier). Then the parser comes back and tries to match an operator, which fails. It then takes the 3rd alt and does the entire process again, which also fails, collecting thereby the expected tokens shown in the error message.

Comment: I guess the actual question I wanted to ask was: how does ANTLR rewrite the left-recursive `expr` rule? Running `antlr4 -Xlog Playground.g4` helped. Thanks.